# Distribution of $\sum_i iX_i$ when $X_i\sim N(i\mu,1)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm interested in finding the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i$, where $X_i \sim N(i\mu,1)$ independent,  as part of the problem that requires to find the MP level $\alpha$ test for $H_0 \, \mu = \mu_0$ vs. $H_1 \, \mu = \mu_1$, where $\mu_1>\mu_0$.

$\textbf{My attempt}$ edited after reading the comments below:

Since $X_i \sim N(i\mu, 1)$ and the Normal family is a scale family, we have that $iX_i \sim N(i^2\mu, i^2)$. This implies that $\sum_i iX_i \sim N(\sum_i i^2\mu, \sum_i i^2)$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1. $iX_i\sim N(i^2\mu,i^2)$, not $N(i\mu, 1/i^2)$. 2. You are only allowed to sum the means and variances to obtain the final normal distribution if the summands are independent, which you need to check.

Comment: Shouldn’t $iX_i\sim \mathcal{N}(i^2 \mu, i^2)$? (Parameterizing by mean and variance)

Comment: Yes, I see now that $iX_i \sim N(i^2\mu, i^2)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused.  If $$X_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(i \mu, \sigma^2 = 1),$$ then $$iX_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(i^2 \mu, \sigma^2 = i^2).$$  That is to say, both the mean and the variance scale, and not in the way you are suggesting.  Then $$\sum_{i=1}^n i X_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu^*, \varsigma^2),$$ where $$\mu^* = \mu \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \mu,$$ and $$\varsigma^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

Comment: you are right. I should've had that $iX_i \sim N(i^2\mu, i^2 )$ and thus $\sum_i iX_i \sim N(\sum_i i^2 \mu, \sum i^2)$, which is exactly what you got.